# Reading Data from Dynamodb using Alexa with lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to read data from my dynamo db table using alexa, but it seems that my lambda function is not able to access my table.
Here is the code to get data from dynamodb :

```
# Gets the data from dynamodb based on userid

def GetData(session):
    userId = session['user']['userId'].split('.')
    userId = userId[3]
    try:
        response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('guid').eq(str(userId))
        )

        # print ("Got data: " + str(len(response)))
        print(response)
        for item in response['Items']:
            final_response = item["command"]
            tstamp = item["tstamp"]

        if (response['Count'] == 0):
            final_response = "No Data with this userid. You can ask to get the userid"

        else:
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            timestamp = int(round((now - datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)).total_seconds()))
            if ((timestamp - int(tstamp)) > 60):
                final_response = "No Data received from device in past 1 minute"

        return final_response
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

When I ask Alexa my custom question, the only response I get is No Data with this userid. You can ask to get the userid.
When I test run my lambda function, it runs successfully. But it not querying the database.

Comment: I'm not a python guy, but the error seems to indicate that you are asking for the key 'session' on the `event` object, and that it's not there.

Comment: I managed to remove the error. But the lambda function is still not reading data from Dynamo db. When I trigger alexa, she just says : "No Data with this userid. You can ask to get the userid".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store and retrieve based on userId, you can use the persistenceAdapter interface provided in the ASK SDK. It looks like you are not currently using that. I would definitely recommend it as it makes managing of handlers for different Intents much easier (and provides useful abstractions like this one). ASK SDK docs https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/overview.html

The abstraction will allow you to use S3 or Dynamo as an implementer. Here is the dynamoDB library. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/tree/master/ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter

Create and register the Dynamo Adapter using the SkillBuilder constructor (ex): https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-highlowgame/blob/master/lambda/py/lambda_function.py#L16

Use your adapter (ex): https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-highlowgame/blob/master/lambda/py/lambda_function.py#L130

When using the adapter, remember that the dynamo write call does not happen until you save, so you can modify the object at will until you call save. All handler_input objects have a reference to the persistent_attributes through the attributes_manager (this also lets you easily work with session_attributes)

Comment: Thank you so much for introducing me to this. Can you please give me an example where alexa and dynamodb are connected using ask-sdk.

Comment: Check out the links above to the python highlow game sample. Here is the root of the project: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-highlowgame/